# Starting MongoDB with SystemD by listening to a Socket

Tags: mongodb, systemd

I'd like to run MongoDB on my development machine whenever the Port 27017 requested but not before that. I already got parts of the file **/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.socket** but now I'm stuck what else goes in there and I don't know if this is the right directory.

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=27017

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My question is basically: What else do I need to write in the file, where do I place this file and do I have to do more than run `systemctl enable mongodb.socket` after that?

Answer (score 2):

Services need special support to work with systemd's socket activation. The connection is passed via file handles at startup and the service should check if environment variable **LISTEN_FDS** is set. At the moment mongodb does not support this kind of invocation.
The path **/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.socket** would be technically correct, but for custom unit files **/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.socket** should be preferred.